# Insert two values to two column in SQL Server from one Excel row

Tags: sql-server, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have some Excel rows like this:

```
Element                                                                             amount full amount
'8671301930 - ZESZYT A-4 100XKARTKOWY W KRATKĘ OPRAWA TWARDA ARTYKUŁ PAPIERNICZY'    0,48     480
'0035804613 - OLEJ DO PRZEKŁADNI PRZEMYSŁOWYCH MINERALNY TRANSOL CLP DIN CLP'        1,25     550
```

How can I split cell 'Element' to two separate rows in SQL Server and make '8671301930' and all further numbers from 'element'- primary key using python and pandas?

Answer (score 1):

[image: If I understood your question correctly, that's the answer.]

If I understood your question correctly, that's the answer.

Comment: Error:     df['Element'], df['Opis'] = zip(*df[1].apply(lambda s : (s[:11], s[13:])))
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Instead of column name 'Element' you used index (df[1]). Index 1 selects column 'amount' not 'Element'.

Comment: I used df[1] because this is second column in xls, also i can't use name 'element' because there is no headers in those sheets so only index remains to establish a column. Everything works when i added a headers but in the future cant do it.


`df = pandas.read_excel(path, header=None, index_col=False)
    df['Element'], df['Opis'] = zip(*df[1].apply(lambda s : (s[:11],s[13:])))`